# Module to create tokens that insert node field data based on node title

Tags: tokens

I have a Date entity bundle based on node that has a date field (starting and ending).  I would like to be able to give my content admin's the ability to insert a date with a non-techie friendly token.

For example, I have a node titled "Attendee Registration Opens" with a date value of December. Ideally a writer, creating a page or article or any other node, could simply do [attendee_registration_opens:start_date], which they would pick from a fieldset.

I am currently playing with token_filter and token_insert but, as far as I can tell, these do not allow me to use a token that, again, shows one field from a different node.